# WYSIWYG rich text editor that supports diffs?

Tags: javascript, diff, richtextbox

My web application is similar to StackOverflow in that different users frequently edit the same blob of text.

Currently we only support plain text, and therefore it's easy to show users how the text has changed between edits.

I want to support rich text in these fields, but my users are non-technical and therefore markup of any kind is not an option.

**Are there any javascript-based rich text editors that support diffs?** Ideally the diffs would be in rich text as well, but if necessary they could be rendered in markdown or similar (I'd like to avoid raw HTML at all costs).

Comment: dunno but please post if you find one. SO uses WMD for the wysiwyg-ness, see http://wmd-editor.com/ -- not sure of the diffs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone can authoritatively answer no to this question, but I've never heard of a Javascript WYSIWYG editor that does diffs.

Stack Overflow does diffs on the server side. You'll probably have better luck if you look for a server-side component to do the job. If you need to show the diff as the user types, or something like that, you could use AJAX to hand off the diff work to the server.

Comment: I agree.  I'd do the diff's on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Xopus 4 supports live [tracking of text changes](https://xopus.com/xopus-4-released.html). As opposed to a diff change tracking allows you to follow and accept/reject the changes of multiple users.

Xopus is a web based WYSIWYG XML editor so you can have it edit your own XML flavor.